# How can you keep an animation from a navbar-element on the last keyframe while on the current page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom animation that when you hover a link a line flows from left to right (See example: https://jsfiddle.net/mxfiddle/fubLo45j/2/).

I want the line to stay for the current page I am on.

I am totally new to web development in general so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

My code for adding an active class:

```
// Get the container element
var navbarContainer = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get all navbar elements with class="navElement" inside the container
var navElement = navbarContainer.getElementsByClassName("navElement");

// Loop through the navbar elements and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < navElement.length; i++) {
  navElement[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your pages:

```
document.body.onload = function() {
// on page load
  document.querySelectorAll("#navbar a").forEach(a => {
//catch all links in navbar
    a.href === location.pathname ? a.classList.add("active") : a.classList.remove("active")
// if navbar link is the same as current loacation pathname add active class, if not remove it.
  })
};
```

You need ether something like this or saving clicked item in local storage and read it on other page...

And I hope you do understand you can simply remove active class from home and put on a current link in HTML depending on page you are on...